# Main.JS taking more than sufficient load time

Tags: apex, visualforce, performance

I have created a site which is taking more than sufficient load time. After checking the loading in various tool found that a JS file that is main.js is the main culprit and it is an internal file coming from salesforce.

This file is not coming in all the pages and taking sufficient load time. Is there any way to decrease the time as well as why this file is used.

Comment: Are you saying that `main.js` takes a long time to load on some pages and you want to reduce this load time?

Comment: Yes , And want to know why it reference in some of the pages and not in all

Comment: Probably won't be included with `showHeader="false"`.

Comment: Already using showheader=false.  Across all

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?